# slider en js problemas para leer las imagenes BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, blob, slider

Tengo armado un código que funciona perfectamente en otra web, pero en esta que es una renovación me está dando inconvenientes, adjunto el error y el código:

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\claromeconet.com\componentes\imagenes.php on line 3

Código:

```
<?php
$image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`hash` FROM `img_alq` WHERE `estado`='1' AND `idalq`='{$prop['id']}' ORDER BY `orden` ASC;");
$images = mysql_num_rows($image_query);
?>

<div class="imagen-propiedad">
    <div class="slider">
        <?php if($images==0){
            echo '<img src="/images/BannerProximamente200x150.png" />';
        }
        while($row_image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)){
            echo "<img src=\"/images/200x150.php?para=alq&id={$row_image['id']}&hash={$row_image['hash']}\" />";
        }
        mysql_free_result($image_query)?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if($images>1){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#prop_<?php echo $prop['id'] ?> .slider').slidesjs({
            width:200,
            height:150,
            navigation:{active:false},
            play:{interval:5000,auto:true},
            fade:{speed:300}
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Código del 200x150.php:

```
<?php
include('../../componentes/var.php');
set_time_limit(20);
if(isset($_GET['id']) and preg_match($expr_idusuario,$_GET['id'])){
    if(isset($_GET['hash']) and preg_match($expr_hash_reg,$_GET['hash'])){
        if(isset($_GET['para']) and preg_match("/^(alq|user|hotel|album|serv){1}$/",$_GET['para'])){
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT `200x150`, `hash`, `estado` FROM `img_{$_GET['para']}` WHERE `id`='{$_GET['id']}' LIMIT 1;");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
                $img=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                if($img['hash']==$_GET['hash']){
                    if($img['estado']){
                        $expires = 60*60*8;
                        header("Pragma: public");
                        header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
                        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
                        header("Content-type: image/png");
                        echo $img['200x150'];
                    }else echo 'Deshabilitada.';
                }else echo 'Hash incompatible.';
            }else echo 'Sin resultados.';
        }else echo 'Para erroneo.';
    }else echo 'Hash erroneo.';
}else echo 'ID erroneo.';
?>
```

Basicamente lo que hace este codigo es leer en una tabla "img_alq" algunas imagenes en formato BLOB "200x150", luego arma un slider con el pequeño js de abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De entrada el error claramente está en la línea 3 de tu archivo `imagenes.php` y dice que la función `mysql_num_rows` espera un recurso como primer parámetro y recibió un valor `boolean`.  Básicamente te falta código para verificar que se haya ejecutado la consulta satisfactoriamente.  El resultado de la función `mysql_query` puede ser un recurso o un `boolean` con valor `false` si ocurrió un error en la ejecución de la consulta.  En caso de que el resultado sea `false` lo conducente es que llames la función `mysql_error` para obtener la información del error.

Sin embargo, más allá de este problema, el código sigue utilizando las funciones `mysql_*` las cuales ya se consideran obsoletas, además de que es vulnerable a inyecciones de código SQL.  Por lo que te recomiendo modifiques el código para utilizar PDO o las funciones `mysqli_*` y que también utilices comandos preparados con parámetros en lugar de crear una cadena de comando SQL dinámicamente como lo hace el código actual.